# Change post index in WP_Query object WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WooCommerce on WordPress blog. I want to sort product by price, and order ASC (100, 200, 400, 500,...) but these products with price set to zero or empty (not set) are moved to end of the list (will be displayed in the last paged of pagination).

I tried to edit query by using the_posts filter, but it not working. I will thank you very much if someone can help me.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => '_price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to share your query code, in order for us to help you. Please edit your question.

Comment: Thank you @mevius, I've updated my post.

Comment: I think you may need to write an SQL query, or use multiple queries (one for empty or NULL product prices, and the other for products with prices).

Comment: But how can I use pagination for multiple queries?

Comment: This may help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130009/how-to-merge-two-queries-together

Comment: Thank you very much @rnevius, now I can fix the problem. The code is too long but it works.